# How to get minimum number of passes in Bubble_sort program(Python programming)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have attached my bubble sort program. It gives the correct answer but gives the maximum number of passes. If I give input as `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]` then also it gives a number of passes=6. I am trying to get a minimum number of passes to get program run. that means for the given example 1 or 2 passes because they already are in ascending order.

How would I get the minimum number of passes??

```
def bubbleSort(list):
     global count
     count=0;
     for num in range(0,len(list)-1):
         count=count+1

         for i in range(0,len(list)-1-num):
                   if list[i]>list[i+1]:
                    list[i], list[i+1] = list[i+1], list[i]

         print("pass",count, ":",list)

     return(list,count)

    list=[]
    list1=[]
    str=str(input("Enter the elements of the list seperated by comma:"))
    list1=str.split(",")
    for i in list1:
        list.append(int(i))
    print("Original List:",list)

    bubbleSort(list);
    print("Sorted list:",list)
    print("Number of Passes:",count)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This seems like home work. your problem it the for loop, because the for loop will go through every item and increase your loop count. Use another type of loop where you can set the next start position, and do some conditioning if the next item should be sorted or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your outer loop should count backwards so that the larger values as moved to the back by the inner loop can stay in the back, and it should stop just before 0 because the last item left must be the smallest.

Change:

```
for num in range(0,len(list)-1):
```

to:

```
for num in range(len(list)-1, 0, -1):
```

Comment: Do you have any suggestions that which loop I can use..?? I tried it with using while and if loop but it did not work.

Comment: @PGP `if` is not a loop. It's a condition. And use `for` loop only as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @Ayush Kumar.. Thank you for the suggestion.